# Pod install stuck on infinite loop react native

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I'm facing a problem while running Pod install. When it is finished installing all pods, it gets stuck on a loop printing React-core and the paths of these two files .release.xcconfig, .debug.xcconfig.

```
React-Core

/path/project/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-project/Pods-project.release.xcconfig

/path/project/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-project/Pods-project.debug.xcconfig

/path/project/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-project-projectTests/Pods-project-projectTests.release.xcconfig

/path/project/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-project-projectTests/Pods-project-projectTests.debug.xcconfig
```

It was working fine before I clean cache and files.
The previous steps I did to get this problem were:

1. Cleaning cache with yarn cache clean
2. Remove pods and Podfile.lock
3. Run pod install

this is my podfile:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '12.0'

use_frameworks!
pre_install do |installer|
  installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
    if pod.name.start_with?('RNFB') || pod.name.eql?('RNPermissions') || pod.name.start_with?('Permission-')
      def pod.build_type;
        Pod::BuildType.static_library # >= 1.9
      end
    end
  end
end

target 'project' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )

    # react-native-permissions permission handlers
    permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'

    pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera/Permission-Camera.podspec"
    pod 'Permission-MediaLibrary', :path => "#{permissions_path}/MediaLibrary/Permission-MediaLibrary.podspec"
    pod 'Permission-Notifications', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Notifications/Permission-Notifications.podspec"
    pod 'Permission-LocationAlways', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationAlways/Permission-LocationAlways.podspec"
    pod 'Permission-LocationWhenInUse', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationWhenInUse/Permission-LocationWhenInUse.podspec"

    pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
    # pod 'RNGestureHandler', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler'
    
    
    # Add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

    # For Analytics without IDFA collection capability, use this pod instead
    # pod ‘Firebase/AnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport’

    # Add the pods for any other Firebase products you want to use in your app
    # For example, to use Firebase Authentication and Cloud Firestore
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
    
  pod 'RNSVG', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-svg'

  #pod 'react-native-network-info', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-network-info'

  pod 'react-native-camera', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-camera'

  pod 'RNPermissions', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'

  pod 'react-native-image-picker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-picker'

  target 'project' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  #use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
     # some older pods don't support some architectures, anything over iOS 11 resolves that
       config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
    end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

hard to tell but it looks like your Podfile is for a recent version of RN but you have some pods manually linked which should support auto linking. Maybe double check the install/setup instructions for the 3rd party libraries you're using.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of my problema was removing this line of code from my podfile:

installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|

Thank u